# How to handle two different class attribute accesses?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have two classes as follows:

```
class ConfigVariable():
    """ single configuration variable with some attributes """
    def __init__(self, value, description=None):
        self.value = value
        self.description = description

class ConfigManager(dict):
    """ holds several configuration variables """
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        ret = self[name].value
        return ret

var1 = ConfigVariable(True, 'some description')

foo = ConfigManager({'var1': var1})
```

As the value of a variable is used most of time, I don't want to write `foo.var1.value` all the time to get the value of the variable. Thus I manipulate the `__getattr__` method of the `ConfigManager` class to return the value by default:

```
print(foo.var1) # returns 'True'
```

But from time to time I need access to the other attribute(s) of the variable too which isn't working any longer:

```
print(foo.var1.description) # throws AttributeError exception
```

Is there a way for the ConfigManager class to distinguish between those two accesses and handle it appropriately?

Can I catch the exception within the ConfigManager class?

Comment: either use `defaultdict` or use `dictionaryObject.get(key, defaultValue)`

Comment: But `defaultdict` is about missing keys ... as you can see the example `settings` and the following print commands, I don't access  any missing key.

Comment: ***I don't access any missing key.***: But there is no `settings.log` in your second example `class Settings`? [Edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Sure, `print(settings.log)` returns the value which is `True`.
It was defined like this:

`settings = Settings({
    'log':Setting(True, 'Logging enabled/disabled'),
    'log_level':Setting(5, 'Log level, 0=critical, 5=debug')
})`

Comment: The problem is not at all about accessing missing keys but accessing existing keys of which one key is defined as the default.

Comment: Ok, I didn't repeat 'class Setting' from the beginning - fixed.

Comment: Your examples are still confusing using `Setting` and `Settings` as class names.  Is `return self[name]` what you want? See [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/BrownStripedOutcome#main.py)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried to enhance the text. I want to have `return self[name].value` but `print(settings.log.value)` should still work.

Comment: ***a way for the ConfigManager class to distinguish between those two accesses***: No, because `ConfigMangager` is not involved at `.value` it's part of `ConfigVariable`. The `ConfigManager` are able to distinguish between: `foo.var1`, `foo.var1()`, `foo['var1']` and `foo._var1`.